# Minimum pumping length of a regular language

Tags: regular-language, computation

Consider the language

```
L = { a3n + 5 | n ≥ 0 }
```

What is the minimum pumping length of `L` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a computer programming question.

Answer (score 0):

By the minimum pumping length for a regular language `L`, I understand the smallest `p` such that every string `u ∈ L` of length at least `p` can be written `u = xyz` where `|xy| ≤ p`, `y ≠ λ` and `xyiz ∈ L` for all `i ≥ 0`. In your case, every string `a3n + 5 ∈ L` with `n > 0` can be written:

```
a3n + 5 = a5(a3)ia3
```

where `i ≥ 0`. This decomposition satisfies the above conditions, so the minimum pumping length of `L` is `8`. Note that `n ≥ 0` does not work because the string `a5` cannot be pumped. Note also that the minimal DFA for `L` has `8` states, although in general the minimum pumping length for a regular language can be less than the number of states in its minimal DFA.